# How to keep an image at 50% of the page and containing its height

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a container and in the container are two sections, both at 50% width. In the right side container is an image. I want the left and right boxes to both be the same height at all times and the image to always be 50% width at all times as well.

I cannot figure out how to always keep the image at full height and width of the container without completely making the image look awful. Even if some parts of the image are cut out, that would be fine.

How can I go about doing this?

```css
html, body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
#box-container {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
}
#box1, #box2 {
 width: 50%;
 height: 500px;
 display: inline-block;
}
#box1 {
 background: blue;
}
#box2 {
}
#box2 img {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="box-container">
 <div id="box1">
 </div><div id="box2">
  <img src="http://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/demolition1.jpg" alt="">
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: use max-width:100% and max-height:100% for the img

Comment: This doesn't make the image the full 100% width.

Comment: Dont use an `<img>` tag, use `background-image`. Then you can set `background-size` and `background-position`.

Answer (score 2):

you have to give the image `height:100%;` and `width:auto;` and to the container  `overflow:hidden;`

```css
html, body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
#box-container {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
    overflow:hidden;
  
}
#box1, #box2 {
 width: 50%;
 height: 500px;
 display: inline-block;
}
#box1 {
 background: blue;
}
#box2 {
}
#box2 img {
 width: auto;
 height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="box-container">
 <div id="box1">
 </div><div id="box2">
  <img src="http://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/demolition1.jpg" alt="">
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Should mention that the overflow property is going to actually cut the image off, so they need to resize their images accordingly or utilize vectors.

Comment: Even if some parts of the image are cut out, that would be fine. this was in the question

Comment: This is getting pretty close, but the image doesn't get wide enough. The `width: auto` stops it from getting to the 100% width.

Comment: you want always to see 100% width?

Comment: I want the image to fully cover the container it is in.

Answer (score 0):

I believe flex could make it. You could use bootstrap row class, like this: 
div class="row" style="display:flex;"

and then, instead of box1 and box2, use the classes div class="col-md-6" for each one (they fit half [50%] of the div that contains it). Give it a try. Sorry for the poor english.

Answer (score 0):

```
    #box1, #box2 {
        width: 50%;
        height: 500px;
        display: inline-block;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
   #box2 img {
       /* width: 100%; */
         height: 100%;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is, what you want to achieve

```
<style>
    .boxes{
        width:50%;
        float:left;
        border:1px solid black;
        box-sizing:border-box;
        height:1000px;
    }

    img{
        max-width:100%;
    }
    #sectionOne{
        background-image:url("http://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/demolition1.jpg");
    }
</style>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="boxes" id="sectionOne">
        <!-- <img src="http://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/demolition1.jpg"> -->
    </div>
    <div class="boxes">
        THis is the noather Div
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment out the the #serctionOne part and un comment the <img> tag for another version.